Can I leave South Africa before 90 days and go back for another month?
I’ve seen a similar question was asked a few years ago but I’m reposting it in case something has changed.
I’m planning to be in South Africa for 3 months (visa-free), go back to my home country (UK) for a few days, and then travel back to SA for an additional month. Does anyone have any experience in doing so and can confirm this’s legal?
Is there any specific amount of time you need to be out of SA before returning?
I can’t find anything official online, if you found a website/statement would you please post a link of the source you took this info from?
Thank you in advance!

Does this answer your question? Can I leave South Africa before my 90 days expire, and return after a few days to stay for another 90 days?

You might consider applying for a short-term visa that would allow you to spend 120 days instead of having to leave and come back. Might be much cheaper than an extra round-trip ticket, and it eliminates any worry or concern.

If you were to leave and come back, my understanding is that you would be able to leave South Africa and go back and be eligible for another 90 days, however, if your frequent visits start to look like employment or residency it could raise concerns with immigration officials. As long as you have proper documentation stating the nature of the trip all should be fine. There isn't an official stipulation on how much time should pass between visits but there should be an understanding that you are not looking to permanently move in to said country. Two sources in which you could acquire more information would be South African Department of Home Affairs as well as the official visa requirements page for UK citizens.

This is true. But if you spend the maximum time in a country, leave for only a few days and then come back looking to spend the maximum time again, you already look suspicious. You should have a good explanation of why this is necessary.
